# How to populate HTML Toolbox in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019, vs-extensibility, toolbox

I'm coming to you with this question because I'm trying to learn ASP.NET Core MVC pattern and I can't quite remember all the elements in HTML + HTML Helper and so I was thinking of adding them to my toolbox. 
I know of the existence of "Code Snippets" and drag-and-drop to Toolbox but I'm more of a clicky guy and want to **automate this with a VSIX**.

To get what I wanted, I searched the MarketPlace for Extensions and found the [Bootstrap Snippet Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EricLebetsamer.BootstrapSnippetPack). It does what I want by adding some snippets to the Toolbox but I can't quite decipher how does the extension do it. I tried to create a VSIX empty project with some snippets but they can't be found in the tool box (only in Code Snippet Manager):
[my VSIX project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfiQ4.png)

[The result in Code snippets manager but **not in ToolBox**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtlsN.png)

I noticed, with the Bootstrap pack installed, that my .Vssettings file is modified to add these new elements in the toolbox. And it's happening every time I create a new .snippet in the extension installation files so maybe Visual Studio does it automatically ? Don't know and can't find how though with how [minimal the doc on this is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/toolbox-html-tab?view=vs-2019).

So I'd really would like to know how does this extension manage to add HTML snippets to the Toolbox and/or where does the [native HTML toolbox elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ktW0.png) are located (so I could understand their behavior) ?

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found one part of the answer: how to add HTML snippets to the toolbox. Simply use these 2-4 lines in a VSPackage project:

Using to implement

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
```

Code:

```
    DTE2 dte = (DTE2)await this.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE));
    dte.ToolWindows.ToolBox.ActiveTab.ToolBoxItems.Add("name of the Tool in toolbox", _
 "The text of the HTML Snippets", vsToolBoxItemFormat.vsToolBoxItemFormatHTML);
```

You're free to do some more tweaking with DTE to create your own tab etc... [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.toolboxitems.add?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

The fact that it's this easy, took me multiple days and hard to find on Google is annoying.

ALSO the fact that the originally mentioned VSIX (Bootstrap snippets) don't use this method is annoying too and I still can't find an answer to that.

This solution uses DTE and I don't know if it's up to date in VS 2019 and future versions because it seems like it's an old assembly.

And I still couldn't find how the native HTML tools are generated/where are their assemblies (even in debug mode and with the use of watch they can't be found ?!?).